# AWS EC2 Linux IpTables Changes Don't Persist

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables

I run `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` on my AWS EC2 Linux server. The port (`80`) is now unblocked.

Then I go `service iptables save`

It says:

> `iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[  OK  ]`

Then **I reboot my server**.

Once I do, the port (`80`) is blocked again, and I have to type the first command

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Again. And again. And AGAIN!

Why? Is there some other way to persist these changes on an EC2!?

It even loses the settings when I take a live snapshot of my EC2 - so I'm really hoping to fix this, thanks.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/355096/iptables-not-persisting-after-reboot-on-centos-6-2

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit delayed, but I just had the same problem and was able to get it working on a fresh EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```sh
# First configure iptables-persistent so allow for easy install
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/339790/how-can-i-prevent-apt-get-aptitude-from-showing-dialogs-during-installation
echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v4 boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v6 boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent

# create your iptables rules
sudo iptables <rules>

# save them to /etc/sysconfig/rules.v4 which was set for iptables-persistent
sudo bash -c "mkdir -p /etc/sysconfig && iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/rules.v4"

sudo reboot
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an external firewall on all aws instaces you have to open the port in aws.

Go to aws security groups of your instance and create a new incoming rule for the port 80

Comment: I'm talking about iptables not the security groups. I'm aware of security groups but the question is about iptables - which is still possible to configure on an AWS EC2 even with security groups.